# (R) Save data (vector or dataframe) with chinese character/ UTF-8 and windows 10

Tags: r, utf-8, windows-10, cjk, saving-data

I am trying to save some data downloaded from a website that includes some chinese characters. I have tried many things with no success. R studio default text encoding is set to UTF-8, windows 10 region is also set to Beta, use unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support.
Here is the code to reproduce the problem:

````
##package used
library(jiebaR) ##here for file_coding
library(htm2txt) ## to get the text
library(httr) ## just in case
library(readtext)

##get original text with chinese character
mytxtC <- gettxt("https://archive.li/wip/kRknx")

##print to check that chinese characters appear
mytxtC

##try to save in UTF-8
write.csv(mytxtC, "csv_mytxtC.csv", row.names = FALSE, fileEncoding = "UTF-8")

##check if it is readable
read.csv("csv_mytxtC.csv", encoding = "UTF-8")

##doesn't work, check file encoding
file_coding("csv_mytxtC.csv")
## answer: "windows-1252"

##try with txt
write(mytxtC, "txt_mytxtC.txt")
toto <- readtext("txt_mytxtC.txt")
toto[1,2]

##still not, try file_coding
file_coding("txt_mytxtC.txt")
## "windows-1252" ```

For information
``` Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=French_Switzerland.1252;LC_CTYPE=French_Switzerland.1252;LC_MONETARY=French_Switzerland.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=French_Switzerland.1252" ```
````

Comment: The file already comes in encoded as UTF-8. Have you tried [reopening](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532197-Character-Encoding) the text file with UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: yes, I did. also, if I understood correctly it reopen my code file, not the output file. As well, it always fails to save the file as UTF-8 even though the file encoding is set to utf-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the setLocal and it seems like it is working.
I just added this line in the beginning of the code:
`Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE","chinese")`

just need to remember to change it back eventually. And still, I found it weird that this line makes it possible to use UTF-8 for saving while before it was not possible...

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Windows :

Download the file :

```
download.file("https://archive.li/wip/kRknx", destfile="external_file", method="libcurl")
```

Input Text :

```
my_text <- readLines("external_file")  # readLines(url) works as well
```

Check for UTF8 :

> ```
> > sum(validUTF8(my_text)) == length(my_text)
> [1] TRUE
> ```

You can also check the file :

> ```
> > validUTF8("external_file")
> [1] TRUE
> ```

Here's the only [difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) I noticed on Windows :

```
user@somewhere:~/Downloads$ file external_file 
external_file: HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
```

vs

```
user@somewhere:~/Downloads$ file external_file 
external_file: HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
```

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your comment. Your solution seems to work with encoding for me but then doesn't work with htm2txt package. I was thinking to use this package since the html page are quite dirty, it helps to clean them up a bit before saving. I will continue explore a bit your solution though